# Shading artifacts in cycles displacement

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, displacement

I'm trying to make stylized topographic maps in cycles using displacement with 10m resolution hight maps. An early issue I have is getting clean edges. Adding more geometry to the plane does not seem to help. I suspect my image may be too low resolution, but that's the best I can find. Does anyone have a workaround suggestion to clean this up a bit? Many thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, OpenEXR format seems to work better for height map, it may fix your problem? but maybe share your file with the image packed: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: These "torn" shadows are a known issue when working with 90° angle displacements. You could try vector Displacement instead. Increasing the resolution of your image is a bit more tricky. However there is a plethora of external tools or options within Blender to interpolate values in between pixels, to get an image with increased resolution. That should help with the jagged edges.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things come to my mind:

- If it's really the image that's the problem, **upscale and blur** it beforehand. This will smooth any compression/resolution artifacts and could work in your case.
- Are you using **Adaptive Subdivision**? If not, you might want to do
  that. Go to *Render Properties > Feature Set > Experimental*. Then add
  a *Subdivision Surface* modifier set to *Simple* and check *Adaptive
  Subdivision*. In viewport you won't see the full resolution though. Also, make sure to use **Displacement Only**. *Material Settings > Settings > Surface > Displacement >Displacement Only*.
- Try different **interpolations** in the *Image Texture* node.